# How can I extract x and y coordinates from a line in an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, coordinates, extract, feature-extraction

I would like to extract x and y coordinates from this image?

[image]

Is it possible in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this programmatically since you're dealing with a simple line and a clean image with little noise ([a grayscale intensity `uint8` image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-175) in this case). Here's how you can extract your line:

```
img = imread('1ebO0.png');  % Load image
mask = (img < 128);         % Threshold to get a matrix of 0 and 1 (ones where your
                            % line is, zeroes elsewhere)
[~, index] = max(flipud(mask), [], 1);  % Gives you the index of the first row from
                                        % the bottom of the image where a 1 occurs
x = find(any(mask, 1));  % Find indices of columns that have at least one 1 to get x
y = index(x);            % Trim row indices based on the above to get y
plot(x, y);
```

And the line:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's awesome. If you don't mind me asking, I would like to replicate and shift this function to the right and then convolve them. I can duplicate it and shift it but then the convolution gives some weird mega-monster out of it. any idea?

Comment: I am using this code f1 = y;
plot(f1, 'k');
hold on;
x2 = x(:)+10;
f2 = y;
plot(x2,y, 'r');
hold on;
fv = conv(f1,f2, 'full')
plot(fv, 'b');

Comment: @matteoeoeo: You shifted where you plot the data on the axes, but not the data itself: `f1` and `f2` both contain `y`, so you are convolving a vector with itself. Your data `y` also has 1113 points and a max value of 700, so it's not surprising it creates a large result.

Comment: I see thanks. But my 'data itself' is x and y, what can I change of the data if not x? (probably a beginner's question)

Comment: @matteoeoeo: If you want to convolve `y` with a shifted version of itself, you would want to concatenate zeroes onto the beginning of the vector (and perhaps takes points off the end). For example: `yShifted = [zero(1, 10) y(1:(end-10))];`

Comment: Thanks, that works well! If you don't mind me asking one last thing, I'd like to shift the function 'on a sine wave'. After the first one, I would shift its copy 'right and up' along the sine, and so on for the whole cycle of the sine. Can I ask a tip for that kind of shift? thanks!

Comment: @matteoeoeo: I described shifting it rightward above. You would just have to figure out how your sample points for `y` relate to the sample points in your sine wave (ideally the same resolution, so the Nth sample point of your sine wave would mean padding `y` with N zeroes to shift it). Shifting it upward is just a matter of adding the sine value to `y`.

Comment: if you don't mind one extra question after 'the last one', can I use what you taught me here to sum the function and its shifted versions but only in the 'non zero' parts (aka the curve itself, not the additional bit that causes the shift)? Or I need a different strategy altogether? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be using `getpts` function. This function helps you to get some points using mouse selection from the specified fig.

```
[x, y] = getpts(fig)
```

> lets you choose a set of points in the current axes of figure fig using the mouse. Coordinates of the selected points are returned in x and y.

See more in [this documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getpts.html).